# How to make Graph API calls from Angular http://localhost:4200 port?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, localhost, sharepoint-online

I have created one project in Angular. I need to GET/POST data from the SharePoint list.

I have created Microsoft Graph API App to achieve the same.

When I tried to GET/POST data in SharePoint list using Postman. It is working correctly.

But when I integrate that code in Angular and run that project on localhost throws me the below error.

"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ {directoryId}}/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Answer (score 0):

When we develop an Angular app which needs a back end to persist data, the back end is often served on another port of localhost. For example, the URL to the front end Angular app is `http://localhost:4200`, while the URL to the back end server is http://localhost:3000. In this case, if we make an HTTP request from the front end app to the back end server, it is a cross-domain request and we need to do some extra work to make it happen.

- Create a file called `proxy.conf.json` next to our project’s package.json
- Add the following contents to the newly created `proxy.conf.json` file:

  ```
  {
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
  ```

  }
- Edit the `package.json` file’s start script to be:

`"start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",`

for more https://betterprogramming.pub/setup-a-proxy-for-api-calls-for-your-angular-cli-app-6566c02a8c4d